# Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap with nested object

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have problem with nesting data class. Here is my data classes:

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories_table")
data class Category(
    var details: String = "",
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = "",
    var lastUpdated: Long = -1,
    var name: String = "",
    var order: Int = -1,
    val specialities: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
)
```

And here is my DB:
[image: My DB]

I using this code for get data from database:

```
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                categories.clear()
                specialities.clear()
                for (cat in snapshot.children){
                    val category: Category? = cat.getValue(Category::class.java)
                    for (spec in cat.children){
                        spec.getValue(String::class.java)?.let { specialities.add(it) }
                    }
                    category?.let { categories.add(it) }
                }
                _categories.value = categories
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                throw error.toException()
            }
        }

        categoryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

I have red many themes with this problem but can't find solution and always get this error:

```
 Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
```

**Edit**
I have a progress)

```
for (cat in snapshot.children) {
                    val categoryMap: Map<String, Any> = cat.value as Map<String, Any>
                    val category = Category(details = categoryMap.getValue("details").toString(), name = categoryMap.getValue("name").toString(),
                                            id = categoryMap.getValue("id").toString(), lastUpdated = categoryMap.getValue("lastUpdated").toString().toLong(),
                                            order = categoryMap.getValue("order").toString().toInt())
                    categories.add(category)
```

I'm not sure that i'm parsing map correct, but it's work. Tell me please if i wrong)

Comment: How is "categoryRef" defined?

Comment: What do you have inside `biochemistry`, `dentist`, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from `val specialities: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()`.

In order for the specialties in your database screenshot to be seen as a `List`, they'd have a defined order with sequential, numeric keys: `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. What you have however is a bunch of keys, each with a value or a nested object, which is translates to `Map<String, Object>`.

```
val specialities: Map<String, Object> = mapOf()
```